# SpreadsheetML newlines in cells with inlineStr

Tags: spreadsheetml

I can see in shared strings that newlines are pretty simple:

```
<si>
    <r>
        <t>First Line
Second Line</t>
    </r>
</si>
```

But that doesn't seem to translate to inlineStr.  This newline is ignored:

```
<c t="inlineStr">
    <is>
        <r>
            <t xml:space="preserve">First Line
Second Line</t>
        </r>
    </is>
</c>
```

With and without `xml:space="preserve"` is the same.  Replacing the newline with `&#10;` is the same.  Any ideas how to create a newline in a cell using inlineStr?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `<br>` tag?

If it is not working try using **CDATA** sections within the `<t>` element.

It indicate to the XML parser that the text within should be treated as character data and not parsed as XML markup.

```
<c t="inlineStr">
    <is>
        <t><![CDATA[First Line
Second Line]]></t>
    </is>
</c>
```

Comment: I tried both <br> and <![CDATA[First Line
Second Line]]>.  The comment here doesn't allow a newline, but the sheet1.xml does have a newline inside the CDATA between First Line and Second Line.  Both newlines were ignored, and all text was inline.  Do you see a different result?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <t>
 <c r="A1" inlineStr="Line 1<br>Line 2">
 </c>
 </t>
```

you can also ty

```
<c t="inlineStr">
    <is>
        <t>First Line&#13;&#10;Second Line</t>
    </is>
</c>
```

Comment: The <br> is ignored when I try it.  Are you getting a different result?

Comment: it should work; however I will try different approach for you .
keep me posted please

Comment: &#13;&#10; are ignored too.